# Drag and Drop not working on React App. How to implement DndContext into my code

Tags: reactjs

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Calendar, momentLocalizer } from "react-big-calendar";
import moment from "moment";
import withDragAndDrop from "react-big-calendar/lib/addons/dragAndDrop";

import "./App.css";
import "react-big-calendar/lib/addons/dragAndDrop/styles.css";
import "react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css";

const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment);
const DnDCalendar = withDragAndDrop(Calendar);

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    events: [
      {
        start: moment().toDate(),
        end: moment().add(1, "days").toDate(),
        title: "Some title",
      },
    ],
  };

  onEventResize = (data) => {
    const { start, end } = data;

    this.setState((state) => {
      state.events[0].start = start;
      state.events[0].end = end;
      return { events: [...state.events] };
    });
  };

  onEventDrop = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
          <DnDCalendar
              defaultDate={moment().toDate()}
              defaultView="month"
              events={this.state.events}
              localizer={localizer}
              onEventDrop={this.onEventDrop}
              onEventResize={this.onEventResize}
              resizable
              style={{ height: "100vh" }}
          />
        </div>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

When I try running the React App, it posts, but I cannot move the events. I don't know what I am missing. I am currently following a tutorial on making a big-calendar on React, but this is where the tutorial leaves me.
I am guessing there is something to do with DndContext since I was looking at older tutorials where they used DndContext and HTML5Backend, but I do not know how to reciprocate that to the updated codes.
Any help will be appreciated. Please let me know if there are any other information I should share.